# Uninitialized Constant MyClass::Playback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm attempting to use the [ruby-alsa gem](http://projects.tryphon.eu/ruby-alsa) to provide audio playback on the server. Unfortunately, I keep getting an uninitialized constant MyClass::Playback exception when attempting to do so.

I'm very new to Ruby and Rails, so I'm not sure how to resolve this issue. The following has been added to my Gemfile and I have run a bundle install:

```
gem 'ruby-alsa'
```

My controller code looks like this (though I can't even begin to guarantee the validity of the code):

```
# Test audio playback
file = File.open("sample.wav")
#ALSA::PCM::Playback.open do |playback| # This line is commented out because it didn't work
Playback.open do |playback|
  playback.write do |length|
    file.read length
  end
end

file.close
```

**Update:** If I uncomment the following line, I get the same exception (except ALSA is the uninitialized constant):

```
ALSA::PCM::Playback.open do |playback|
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at this briefly, it looks like your Gemfile needs to be:

```
gem 'ruby-alsa', :require => 'alsa'
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks as if your commented-out code is correct; you should be using [`ALSA::PCM::Playback`](http://rubydoc.info/gems/ruby-alsa/0.7/ALSA/PCM/Playback).

Your next problem is that `write` is an instance method of that class. As shown on the page you linked to, it appears that correct usage might be more like:

```
ALSA::PCM::Playback.open do |playback|
  playback.write do |length|
    file.read length
  end
end
```

*(Caveat: I know nothing about ALSA or this gem, so I have no idea what the above should do.)*

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned I commented that line out because it didn't work, either. With the ALSA::PCM:Playback line uncommented, it throws the same exception: uninitialized constant MyClass::ALSA

Comment: In that case, `::ALSA::PCM::Playback` to force top level resolution, but I think this really indicates that the alsa code is not being required properly.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to require it ?

```
require 'ruby-alsa'
```

edit:

Try to require rubygems first

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'ruby-alsa'
```

Comment: I did...unfortunately, I get "no such file to load -- ruby-alsa".

Comment: I really think this is my problem. I ran a "find . -name *alsa* -print" from my projects root directory and nothing was found. Do I need to include the source somewhere in the project? **Edit:** Sorry, SO formatted my alsa text in italics, but it's surrounded by stars for a wildcard search.

Comment: @senfo Goodness gracious, if you are not able to load `ruby-alsa`, of course that's the problem. It would have been helpful if you had included that in your problem description.

Comment: @Phrogz being new to Ruby, I wasn't even sure if this was necessary. After updating my Gemfile, it turns out that was the case (it wasn't necessary).

Answer (score 1):

Your code is inside a class so you need to do this:

```
::ALSA::PCM::Playback.open do |playback|
```

Note the preceding double colon.