# Using ruby-alsa

Tags: ruby, alsa

I finally got my code to [reference the ruby-alsa library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4570540/uninitialized-constant-myclassplayback), but I'm stuck again. Eventually, what I'd like to happen is have an audio file play on the server when an action is invoked from the client side. As such, I have the following code in my controller:

```
File.open('./public/audio/test.wav', 'r') do |f|
  ALSA::PCM::Playback.open do |playback|
    playback.write do |length|
      f.read length
    end
  end
end
```

By reading the [RDoc for the ALSA library](http://rubydoc.info/gems/ruby-alsa/0.7/ALSA), I get the impression I should be using the [write_in_background method](http://rubydoc.info/gems/ruby-alsa/0.7/ALSA/PCM/Playback) from the ALSA::PCM::Playback class. Unfortunately, I can't get the syntax right for getting this method to work. To simply verify I have ALSA working properly, I attempted to use the Playback.write method (note code above). The above code is syntactically correct; however, it plays a sound only for a microsecond, then stops. My guess is the request ends so quickly, it doesn't have enough time to play anything recognizable.

As previously mentioned, my ultimate goal is to have an end-user invoke an action that plays audio back on the server. The file should not stop playing at the end of the HTTP request --it should continue until another action is invoked that stops playback. Knowing that, could somebody please help me with getting the syntax and parameters right for calling the write_in_background method? I'm afraid the [ruby-alsa documentation](http://projects.tryphon.eu/ruby-alsa) I have at this time hasn't been helpful enough for me (as a complete newbie at Ruby).

**Update:** If I replace the above call to the write method with a call to the write_to_background method, I get the following runtime error: cannot add pcm handler (Function not implemented)

**Update 2:** I tried this with a different WAV file and the following code and it plays at warp speed.

```
File.open('./public/audio/sample.wav', 'r') do |f|
  ALSA::PCM::Playback.open do |playback|
    playback.write do |length|
      @temp = length
      f.read length
    end
    sleep 4
  end
end
```

It appears there may be a combination of things going on here. I believe the first is in reference to the sample rate (length == 44100, which is CD quality). I'll have to look into how to play back audio files at a different rate. Beyond that, however, I'm still stuck on how to get it to play in the background. While the sleep proves ALSA is working, it won't work well in a real-world scenario.

**Update 3:** Got the sample rate bit working even though it temporarily relies on a magic number:

```
File.open('./public/audio/sample.wav', 'r') do |f|
  ALSA::PCM::Playback.open "default", {:channels => 1, :sample_rate => 11025} do |playback|
    playback.write do |length|
      @temp = length
      f.read length
    end
    sleep 4
  end
end
```

At this point, I have my ruby code playing audio through ALSA, but I'm not sure how to make it play continuously in the background without requiring the sleep.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about kicking it off on its own thread?

```
Thread.new do
  File.open('myfile.wav', 'rb') do |f|
    ALSA::PCM::Playback.open do |playback|
      playback.write do |length|
        f.read length
     end
    end
  end
end.join
```

**Edit**:
OK, if that doesn't work, I'm guessing it kicks off its own thread already. How about sleeping for the duration? First try:

```
  File.open('myfile.wav', 'rb') do |f|
    ALSA::PCM::Playback.open do |playback|
      playback.write do |length|
        f.read length
     end
    end
  end
  sleep 4 # seconds
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the same thing --it plays a quick "bleep" then immediately stops. I want to point out I am not sure I'm using the library correctly, at all. I just replaced the sample code I found on the ruby-alsa home page, which references $stdin, with my own file.

Comment: Interestingly enough, the exact same "bleep" except the HTTP request lasts four seconds longer. Not what I expected.